# PHP For Loop to build insert string

Tags: php, insert, mysqli

I'm trying to insert several values into a database.

First I add these values to array (function/other code omitted):

```
$name = (isset($_POST['name']) ? ($_POST['name']) : "name");
$email = (isset($_POST['email']) ? ($_POST['email']) : "email"); 
$username = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$password = $mysqli->real_escape_string(md5($_POST['password']));
```

Like so:

```
$formvars = array();
array_push($formvars, $name, $email, $username, $password);
```

Then call function to insert:

```
    $sql = array(); 
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($formvars);$i++) {
            $sql[] = $formvars[$i];
        }

        print_r(implode(',', $sql));

        $qry = 'INSERT INTO chinesegame (name, email, username, password) VALUES '. implode(',' , $sql);

        if(!$mysqli->query($qry))
        {
            echo "Error inserting data to the table \nquery:$qry";
            return false;
        }        

    return true;
```

My DB structure is as such:

[image]

It's giving me an insert error:

> Error inserting data to the table query:INSERT INTO chinesegame (name,
>   email, username, password)
>   Dan,dthusky@gmail.com,danman,827ccb0eea8a706c4c34a16891f84e7b

Can I not build an insert string like that?

Comment: Strings ought to be quoted in SQL context. Also have you considered bound parameters?

Comment: @mario I have trouble using those, so I went with real_escape_string. And can you elaborate on the string quotes in the SQL context

Comment: Yes, `mysqli` is pretty awkward to use correctly. Check out [`pdo_query()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php/20767765#20767765).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot your "VALUES" keyword. and parenthesis help too. You also need all of the values to be in quotes, here is the correct version:

```
$qry = 'INSERT INTO chinesegame (name, email, username, password) VALUES ("'. implode('","' , $sql). '")';
```

Also, mysqli->query takes a connection variable first which has the connection information to the database, it should look like this:

```
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
if(!$mysqli->query($connection, $qry))
```

Also, for the record,

```
    $sql = array(); 
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($formvars);$i++) {
        $sql[] = $formvars[$i];
    }
```

could be replaced with

```
$sql = $formvars;
```

there is no reason to loop through the whole thing getting them one at a time.

Comment: Okay oops haha. So it's still producing the insert error even with the quotes fixed

Comment: Can you print $qry before it is run and paste it here?

Comment: Do I need to account for the autoincrement Primary key for the id? Also, print gives: INSERT INTO chinesegame (name, email, username, password) VALUES ("Dan","dthusky@gmail.com","danman","827ccb0eea8a706c4c34a16891f84e7b")

Comment: print mysqli_error(); after you do the query in the if statement before you return. Copy that here.

Comment: The auto increment will work automatically, no worries there.

Comment: Yeah I've already included a connection php file at the top of this php file

Comment: Well use that connection variable, it has to be sent to the mysqli->query function.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing a few things in the insert statement:

```
$qry = 'INSERT INTO chinesegame (name, email, username, password) '. implode(',' , $sql);
```

Try changing the insert statement to something like:

```
$qry = 'INSERT INTO chinesegame (name, email, username, password) VALUES ('. implode(',' , $sql).')';
```

Comment: The values need to be in quotes, I got you a correct version above.